# ¿Como hago que Hibernate.initialize() inicialice valores?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

estoy intentando sacar los datos de una tabla que relaciona dos tablas entre si para tener los ids de una de las tablas relacionadas, pero cuando uso Hibernate.initalize() para sacar los datos de la tabla, los objetos resultantes siguen estando sin inicializar, siendo todavía de tipo similar a `Extras_$$_jvst6e4_6a` , en vez de simplemente `Extras`.

Adjunto el código de la función:

```
    public ArrayList getListaExtras(int idTrayecto,SessionFactory sb){ //Ambos valores vienen de un servlet
       Session sesion=sb.openSession();
      
       String ordenHQL="from TrayectosExtra where idTrayecto='"+idTrayecto+"'";
       Query q=sesion.createQuery(ordenHQL);
       ArrayList ListaExtras=(ArrayList)q.list();
       ArrayList ListaFinal=new ArrayList();
       for (int i=0; i<ListaExtras.size(); i++){
           TrayectosExtra ExtraActual=(TrayectosExtra) ListaExtras.get(i);
           Hibernate.initialize(ExtraActual.getExtras());
           ListaFinal.add(ExtraActual);
       }
       sb.close();
       return ListaFinal;
   }
```

En teoría `Hibernate.initialize(ExtraActual.getExtras());` debería inicializar el objeto Extras de ExtraActual, pero según el depurador esto no ocurre: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La llamada a `Hibernate.initialize()` no sustituirá el proxy por un objeto "no proxy", simplemente se asegura que todos los campos de dicho objeto proxy estén inicializados. Es decir, los getters de dicho objeto no te darán excepciones del tipo `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` cuando estés fuera de la sesión.